# Iceface 1.8 not working properly in IE11

Tags: icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I come across a wired issue with Icefaces in IE11. Once I submit a page via partial command button. The page has no response at all. There is nothing happened at all. And the issue cannot be simulated in another computer with IE11. I cannot figure out what's going on? I'm concern about the IE issue. Some versions of IE cannot be compatible with Icefaces stuff very well. But I cannot find obviously evidence. Does anyone have the same or similar issue? Any clue will be great to me. Appreciate very much.